# solving for x : $ {3^{x-1}} / {2^{x-7} } = 1 $ rules for logarithm.

Tags: calculus

$ {3^{x-1}} / {2^{x-7} } = 1 $

$ {3^{x-1}} = {2^{x-7} }  $

now here I can take log with base 2 or 3 on both sides but it will simplify only left or right side.
for example:

$ log_3 {3^{x-1}} = log_3 {2^{x-7} } $

$ {{x-1}} = log_3 {2^{x-7} } $

but not sure how can I solve further for x using rules for logarithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take the natural logarithm of both sides, we get the following:
$$(x - 1)\ln(3) = (x - 7)\ln(2)$$
$$\ln(3)x - \ln(3) = \ln(2)x - 7\ln(2)$$
$$(\ln(3) - \ln(2))x = \ln(3) - 7\ln(2)$$
$$\boxed{x = \frac{\ln(3) - 7\ln(2)}{\ln(3) - \ln(2)}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: taking the logarithm of both sides we obtain $$(x-1)\log(3)=(x-7)\log(2)$$
now you must isolate $x$

Comment: when you say taking log on both sides i assume you mean natural log. right?

Comment: yes i mean the natural log

Answer (score 1):

$$\left (\frac32 \right )^{x} = \frac{3}{2^7} \implies x = \frac{\log{\left ( \frac{3}{2^7}\right )}}{\log{(3/2)}} = \frac{\log{3}-7 \log{2}}{\log{3}-\log{2}}$$